# How to move text up as characters increase android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, textview

I need to do exactly the same as in the picture below:

[image]

I have two `TextView`: Title and Description. The description is always short, so you can ignore it. But with the title it is more difficult. It can be both short and long. Moreover, with an increase in the number of characters, it should go up without shifting the description. How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it reactive, you can set it up in a `ConstraintLayout` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="300dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="#CCCCCC"
    >
    
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
        />
    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stuff"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/divider"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
        />
    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Description"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/divider"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: A blueprint render of the layout]

How it basically works:

- the `Guideline` is there to position the bottom of the text / top of the description. Obviously there are a lot of ways you could do this, depending on the description's length and appearance, and how you want the whole layout to look - this way always puts it right in the middle
- the *description* is constrained between the Guideline and the bottom of the containing View, with a bias of *0%* so it's pushed *up* against the Guideline
- the *text* is constrained between the top of the View and the top of the Guideline, but with a bias of *100%* so it's pushed *down* against the guideline.
- the text uses a `wrap_content` height so it can expand. Because the bias keeps the bottom of the view against the Guideline, it expands *up*
- the parent `ConstraintLayout` has a height of `wrap_content` so it can grow if there's enough *text* that it needs to expand to show it. It also has a `minHeight` to set a baseline height - basically you can define how it looks by default, but allow it to grow as necessary

---

If you don't want it to grow, and want the text area to be scrollable instead, you need to wrap it in a `ScrollView` instead - basically replacing the `TextView` in the layout

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/divider"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stuff"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        />
</ScrollView>
```

And now you have a scrolling area that fills the space between the constraints, and the `TextView` in there has its content aligned to the bottom. The `fillViewport` property on the `ScrollView` makes it so the `TextView` expands to fill the visible area even when it doesn't have enough content, which keeps its bottom pinned to the bottom of the `ScrollView` where you expect the text to be

Answer (score 1):

Give the TextView a fixed amount of dp of height, big enough to accommodate a long title. Also give it `gravity="bottom|left"`.